# Reference variable value using Grafana text graph

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

Is there any way to create some "info box" which doesn't relate to numbers?

For example, querying the following:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="test4", pod=~"api.*", container!=""}
```

will return this result:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="api", image="myacr.azurecr.io/api:3.3.0", pod="api-f6b7657c7-f65nz", namespace="test4"}
```

From this, I want to extract the image name, and create a text of:

```
api image: myacr.azurecr.io/api:3.3.0
```

I tried to use "text" as a graph, but a "text" doesn't have any query ability, only a a static markup

the reason I need it is to see all images by pod name of current choosen namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that using graph of type "Text" in grafana, you can add inline access to variables.
Steps:

1. create a variable
2. optional: set the variable "hide" mode to "variable" (unless u actually need it for your dashboard).
3. create a graph of type "Text" and in the content use $my_variable_name to reference the variable!

Cheers, if it helped anyone.